# Ruby sqlite3 gem not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I recently downloaded Crunchbang and am downloading a Ruby program. I installed Ruby:

```
apt-get install ruby
apt-get install rubygems
apt-get install sqlite3
```

When I run the file, I get:

```
root@crunchbang:/Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack# ruby zackattack.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find sqlite3 (= 1.3.6) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack/lib/zfdb.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack/clients/ews.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack/lib/zfclient.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack/lib/zfhttpd.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from zackattack.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

I am completely at a loss. Help is appreciated/

Comment: provide output of `gem list`

Comment: `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.5.2)`
There is an error installin sqlite3 gem (as mentioned below)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ruby gem as well:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

If your program has a Gemfile, do:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Another advise, install ruby via RVM, it will save you from a number of headaches.

UPDATE:

Most likely you will also need the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: THanks! Now I'm getting this error on the `gem install sqlite3`:
`root@crunchbang:/Pentest/NTLMRelay/ZackAttack# gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***`

Comment: That error is because apt is only installing the basics for SQLite to get it working without supplying the needed headers so the drivers can be compiled. It's a problem I've run into repeatedly trying to use apt and yum, and, as a result, I always install my languages from source. Languages move a lot faster than the repo builders.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) as follows using [apt](/questions/tagged/apt):

```
apt-get install ruby-sqlite3
```

or in my case:

```
apt-get install sqlite3-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid installing Ruby using `apt-get` because you'll face a lot of problems (versions, gem management, etc) down the road. Use RVM instead.

Remove your `apt-get` installations (especially if your `ruby -v` returns something before 1.9) and then follow the instructions at http://rvm.io/rvm/install

RVM will allow you to install multiple Ruby versions and manage your gems more easily.

Once you're done with the rvm installation, do the following:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.6
```

Once you have RVM running, things should become easier... Don't worry about the extra time you're spending in the beginning, it'll pay off :-)